# add property to interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, extend

I have an interface (from another Framework that I cannot directly modify) that looks like the following:

```
public interface IUserDemo
{
string UserName { get; }
}
```

I would like to 'extend' this interface so it looks like the following:

```
public interface IUserDemo
{
string UserName { get; }
string Password { get; }
}
```

The solution will hopefully allow me to do the following:

```
  UserDemo demouser = new UserDemo();
  return new UserDemo
   {            
      UserName = userName,
      Password = password
   };
```

Where UserDemo simply looks like:

```
public class UserDemo : IUserDemo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone can nudge me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend `IUserDemo` like the following

```
public interface IMyUserDemo : IUserDemo
{
    string Password { get; }
}
```

Implement your extended interface `IMyUserDemo`

```
public class UserDemo : IMyUserDemo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```